# Module::Install and bash completion scripts

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script with the following `Makefile.PL`:

```
# Load the Module::Install bundled in ./inc/
use lib '.'; # added since from Perl 5.26 '.' is no more in @INC
use inc::Module::Install;

##############################################################################
# Define metadata (we read it from the binary)

name              'check_updates';
version_from      'check_updates';
perl_version_from 'check_updates';
all_from          'check_updates.pod';

##############################################################################
# Specific dependencies

include 'version';

my %prereqs = (
    'Carp'     => 0,
    'English'  => 0,
    'POSIX'    => 0,
    'Readonly' => 0,
    'Monitoring::Plugin' => 0,
    'Monitoring::Plugin::Threshold' => 0,
    'Monitoring::Plugin::Getopt' => 0,
);

install_script  'check_updates';

auto_install;

tests 't/*.t';
test_requires 'Test::More'       => 0;
test_requires 'File::Spec'       => 0;

# https://metacpan.org/pod/release/DAGOLDEN/CPAN-Meta-2.142690/lib/CPAN/Meta/Spec.pm#license
license 'gpl_3';

WriteMakefile(
    PREREQ_PM            => \%prereqs,
    INSTALLSCRIPT        => '/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/contrib',
    INSTALLSITESCRIPT    => '/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/contrib',
    MAN1PODS             => { 'check_updates.pod' => 'blib/man1/check_updates.1', },
    MAN3PODS             => { },
);
```

I would also like to copy a bash-completion script (i.e. `check_updates.completion`) to the correct directory (given by `pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion`, e.g. `/opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions`)

Is there a way to generate a Makefile rule to just copy the file to the directory?

The execution of `pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion` can also be performed in `Makefile.PL` generating a Makefile with a hardcoded rule.

Comment: Is this problem specific to `Module::Install` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Any solution would be Ok ...

Comment: See also [Installing additional files at install time with ExtUtils::MakeMaker/Dist::Zilla (dzil)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53092475/2173773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::AutoInstall#Customized-MY::postamble) in `Module::AutoInstall` :

> Starting from version 0.43, `Module::AutoInstall` supports modules that
> require a `MY::postamble` subroutine in their `Makefile.PL`. The
> user-defined `MY::postamble`, if present, is responsible for calling
> `Module::AutoInstall::postamble` and include the output in its return
> value.

I tested this with this simple `Makefile.PL`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use inc::Module::Install;

name           'My-Module';
all_from       'lib/My/Module.pm';
include        'Module::AutoInstall';

my %prereqs = (
    'Carp'     => 0,
    'English'  => 0,
    'POSIX'    => 0,
    'Readonly' => 0,
);
install_script 'myscript';
auto_install;

WriteMakefile(
  PREREQ_PM            => \%prereqs,
);

sub MY::postamble {
    my $dest_path = "/opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions";
    my $script_name = "check_updates.completion";
    my $str = "install::\n\t\$(CP) ${script_name} ${dest_path}\n";
    return &Module::AutoInstall::postamble . $str;
}
```

and it seems to work fine here (it copies the given file to the specified path when you run `sudo make install`)